How to use map function in react JS? I cannot run the loop using map function for looping a component code. How can I run it?
App.js specific code:
<Container>
        <Row>
          {blog.map((v, i) => (
            <ProductItems key={i} blog={v}/>
          ))}
        </Row>
      </Container>

function ProductItems() {
  return (
    <Col lg="3" md="6">
      <Card >
        <Card.Img variant="top" src="placeholder.js/100px180" />
        <Card.Body>
          <Card.Title>Card Title</Card.Title>
          <Card.Text>
            Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.
          </Card.Text>
          <Button variant="primary">Go somewhere</Button>
        </Card.Body>
      </Card>
    </Col>
  );
}

blog.jsx code:
export let blog = [
    {
      "blog": [
        {
          "userId": 1,
          "id": 1,
          "title": "are or do repels provide blacked out to accept the option criticizes",
          "body": "because and accepts\naccepts the result of refusal convenient and when which is all\nof our things, but they are the thing that will happen to the architect"
        },
        {
          "userId": 1,
          "id": 2,
          "title": "who is to be",
          "body": "is of things at the time of life\nthey are nothing to follow let the pain of the blessed rebuke those pains and not run away from the caresses of the pleasure, nor any trouble"
        },
        {
          "userId": 1,
          "id": 3,
          "title": "who is to be",
          "body": "is of things at the time of life\nthey are nothing to follow let the pain of the blessed rebuke those pains and not run away from the caresses of the pleasure, nor any trouble"
        },
        {
          "userId": 1,
          "id": 4,
          "title": "who is to be",
          "body": "is of things at the time of life\nthey are nothing to follow let the pain of the blessed rebuke those pains and not run away from the caresses of the pleasure, nor any trouble"
        },
        {
          "userId": 1,
          "id": 5,
          "title": "who is to be",
          "body": "is of things at the time of life\nthey are nothing to follow let the pain of the blessed rebuke those pains and not run away from the caresses of the pleasure, nor any trouble"
        },
        {
          "userId": 1,
          "id": 6,
          "title": "who is to be",
          "body": "is of things at the time of life\nthey are nothing to follow let the pain of the blessed rebuke those pains and not run away from the caresses of the pleasure, nor any trouble"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]


{Description: The blog.jsx contains json code and the objects I am trying to looping through map fuction. The App.js file contains the ProductItems component and function and the map function.}
I tried to repeat the ProductItems code because it has the card code. And were expecting this result that did not happened.

It's just an unnecessarily convoluted object. blog[0].blog.map(...) How can I access and process nested objects, arrays, or JSON?

correct your object declaration. You added some unnecessary stuff.
Instead of:
export let blog = [{
"blog": [....]
}]

it should be:
export let blog = [{
"userId": 1,
"id": 1,
"title": "...",
"body": "...."
}];

For your object
blog[0]?.blog?.map((blog)=>{ 
 return <ProductItems key={blog?.id} blog={blog}/> 
})

this will work
